# How to convert a web page to PDF or image using Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have created a graphics using jquery. and i want to convert this web page to pdf or an image. Which one is simpler? but when I convert this page to pdf that graphic will not shows. can any help me to solve this problem??? please refer some code.

Comment: Please don't ask the same question again.  You can [edit this one](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/5139003/edit) to add more detail, if you want.  Converting HTML to PDF is a massively difficult operation that cannot be done in pure javascript.  You can try calling web services that do this, but rendering HTML as well as any changes to the DOM that javascript performs is highly dependent on what libraries your service is using.

Comment: can you refer some code where I can convert html, javascript to pdf.....

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript is interpreted by the browser, not by the HTML -> PDF application. I'd recommend using [wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/), as it uses Webkit to render, so maybe that would fix your problem.

To try to render the page *that includes* JavaScript, fire up Google Chrome (or another browser with a DOM Inspector of sorts), open your webpage, right click and select **Inspect Element**, right click , click **Edit as HTML**, and copy & paste the HTML into a new text document, save it, and use that instead to convert to a graphics.

You have to go through a complicated process like this because that application that your are using renders only HTML + CSS, and doesn't even parse the JS. The DOM inspector shows the HTML pages as it currently looks, not when it was loaded.

I hope I didn't make it too complicated...

Comment: thakns for your reply...acctually I need an application that is when I click on a button that page will save as a pdf file . it will be an online process.  I have a code ...

Comment: <!-- START: PDF Online Script -->
<script type="text/javascript">
 var authorId = "726419C2-1010-44DC-9ACF-49E766D01774";
 var pageOrientation = "1";
 var topMargin = "0.5";
 var bottomMargin = "0.5";
 var leftMargin = "0.5";
 var rightMargin = "0.5";
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://web2.pdfonline.com/pdfonline/pdfonline.js"></script>
<!-- END: PDF Online Script -->

Comment: It's not possible without a server-side program, which is what you're posting here.

Comment: What's wrong with that script? It seems to be valid. Add it to your question, not this comment thread.

Comment: can you refer some code to covert webpage to image.....this page including jquery graphics

Comment: What do you mean by "jQuery Graphics"?

Comment: this is a div look like a graph where I can drag and drop image ...and I want to save that total div with dropped image as a pdf or image..